# Sum of gridview column

Tags: gridview, yii2

What is the way, if it's possible to sum column values in gridview and display it in summary? I have column with prices and I'd like to show sum of them near rows count.

Comment: post your gridview or code you have tried upon

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. The question is too broad in current state. You can implement it on your own, but I would recommend to use [Kartik's GridView extension](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid). It's enhanced version of native GridView and already has this feature.

Hers is [paragraph in official docs](http://demos.krajee.com/grid#page-summary) desribing this feature.